# Infer type argument from containing class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am trying to create something very similar to how EF Core uses builders in their entity configuration (e.g., `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>`, `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>`, `PropertyBuilder<TEntity>`).

In the below code, I would like the `ObjectBuilder<>` class and `SubObject()` method to infer the type from the class they are implemented in (in this case, `MyClass`). Is this possible?

It would also be great if I could infer the second type from the interface being implemented (the `SomeType` type), but I am pretty sure this is not possible.

It may be that I need a completely different approach to this, but I have yet to come up with an alternate solution.

Thank you for the help.

```cs
public interface ISomeInterface<T2> { }

public class SomeType
{
    public string MySubObjectField { get; }
    public string MySubObjectField2 { get; }
}

public class MyClass : ISomeInterface<SomeType>
{
    public string MyObjectField { get; }
    public string MyObjectField2 { get; }
    
    public MyClass()
    {
        ObjectBuilder<MyClass, SomeType> builder = new ObjectBuilder<MyClass, SomeType>();
        
        builder
            .SubObject<MyClass>(c => c.MyObjectField)
            .HasSomething(t => t.MySubObjectField)
            .IsSomething();

        builder
            .SubObject<MyClass>(c => c.MyObjectField2)
            .HasSomething(t => t.MySubObjectField2);
    }
}

public class ObjectBuilder<T1, T2>
{
    public SubObjectBuilder<T2> SubObject<T1>(Expression<Func<T1, object>> expression)
    {
        // Simplified for question
        return new SubObjectBuilder<T2>();
    }
}

public class SubObjectBuilder<T2>
{
    public SubObjectBuilder<T2> HasSomething(Expression<Func<T2, object>> expression)
    {
        // Do something
        return this;
    }
    
    public SubObjectBuilder<T2> IsSomething()
    {
        // Do something
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you better describe what you'd like to do.  You have 4 classes and an interface defined.  My head explodes whenever I read: _"the ObjectBuilder class infer the type from the class it is being instantiated within"_.  The _within_ throws me off. One idiomatic trick with constructing templated classes is to create a static (non-generic) factory class with the same name. Add a static `Create<T>` generic method where `T` can be inferred from the parameters to `Create`.  In the body method, create a new instance of the generic class.  I can't tell if this would help you

Comment: Type inference requires something at the call site. The type that declares the method is not included in that, nor are type parameters of arbitrary interfaces it implements. Flydog57's suggestion of a `Create<T>` with parameters of the types to infer is a common solution. If it's just about brevity, though, consider using either `var` or the fairly new target-typed `new` syntax to eliminate duplication of the type name with the type arguments.

Comment: @Flydog57, I am trying to create something very similar to how EF Core uses builders in their entity configuration (e.g., `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>`, `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>`, `PropertyBuilder<TEntity>`). Reading over that sentence again, you are correct that it does not make sense. The `ObjectBuilder` class is not actually within `MyClass`. The instance is created inside `MyClass`, but `ObjectBuilder` itself has no knowledge of that. I had a feeling that was the case. I will definitely take a look at a static factory for this and see if it will meet my needs. Thank you!

Comment: It's best if you put that info in the question, and edit it in general to make it clearer

Comment: I actually resolved the issue by adding the concrete implementation type as a generic parameter on the interface : `ISomeInterface<MyClass, SomeType>`. This allowed me to pass the type parameter into the `SubObject()` method rather than repeat it each time. I realize that my question did not actually show the real issue I was having, which is that the `SubObject` method required the type parameter each time it was called. My guess is explaining that would have led to a quicker answer. My apologies. Thank you both for your assistance.